# Adding new user in database from angular+node.js webapp adds/duplicates itself

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express

As I register new user, after few seconds , the same api calls are made(I checked in terminal for data that I logged...api calls are made...not a problem in database) and a duplicate entry of that user is stored in database, it take some time before it duplicates the user. I tried making email field unique to avoid duplicate entries, but then it crashes node server due to MYSQL error for duplicate value for email key. I made user object global, Reset the form after each user, but nothing worked it only delayed duplication a little bit.

HTML Signup Form

```
<div class="container">
    <mat-card class="card">
        <mat-card-title>SIGNUP</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card class="form-card">
            <form [formGroup]="signupForm" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register(form)"> 
                <mat-form-field appearance='outline'>
                    <mat-label>FirstName</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="first_name" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" required/>
                    <mat-error>
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('first_name').hasError('required')">FirstName is <strong>required</strong>.</div>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <mat-form-field appearance='outline'>
                    <mat-label>LastName</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="last_name" type="text" placeholder="LastName" required/>
                    <mat-error>
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('last_name').hasError('required')">LastName is <strong>required</strong>.</div>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
                <mat-form-field appearance='outline' class="full-width">
                    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
                    <mat-icon matSuffix>email</mat-icon>
                    <mat-error>
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('email').hasError('email')">Enter valid Email ID.</div>
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('email').hasError('required')">Email is <strong>required</strong>.</div>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
                <mat-form-field appearance='outline' class="full-width">
                    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="pass" [type]="hidePass ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="Password" required/>
                    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hidePass = !hidePass">
                        <mat-icon>{{hidePass ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-error>
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('pass').hasError('required')">Password is <strong>required</strong>.</div>
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('pass').hasError('minlength')">Password should be <strong>atleast 6 characters long</strong>.</div>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
                <mat-form-field appearance='outline' class="full-width">
                    <mat-label>Confirm Password</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="conf_pass" [type]="hideConfPass ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="Re-enter the Password" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required/>
                    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hideConfPass = !hideConfPass">
                        <mat-icon>{{hideConfPass ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-error> 
                        <div *ngIf="signupForm.hasError('notSame')">Password & Confirm Password does not match.</div>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
                <mat-card-actions>
                    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button class="button full-width" [disabled]="signupForm.invalid">Signup</button>
                </mat-card-actions>
                <button mat-button class="" [routerLink]="'/login'" >Already have an account</button>
            </form>
        </mat-card>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Function that is called on submit

```
register(form: NgForm){
    // Make an User object to store in database.
      this.user = {
      firstname: this.signupForm.controls.first_name.value,
      lastname: this.signupForm.controls.last_name.value,
      email: this.signupForm.controls.email.value,
      password: this.signupForm.controls.pass.value
    }
    this.authService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.statusCode === util.statusCode.OK) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.user);
    form.resetForm();
  }

}
```

Front-End service (authService)

```
registerUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    const cpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const options = {headers: cpHeaders};
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/register-user', user, options)
      .pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
  }
```

Routes

```
router.post('/register-user', (req, res) => {
  authService.registerUser(req.body, (data) => {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Back-End Service (authService)

```
let registerUser = (data, callback) => {
  async.auto({
    user: (cb) => {
      bcrypt.hash(data.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        var dataToSet = {
          "first_name": data.firstname,
          "last_name": data.lastname,
          "email": data.email,
          "password": hash
        }
        userDAO.registerUser(dataToSet, (err, dbData) => {
            if (err) {
                cb(null, { "statusCode":404, "statusMessage": "Server is busy" });
                return;
            }
            cb(null, { "statusCode": util.statusCode.OK, "statusMessage": util.statusMessage.USER_ADDED, "result":dataToSet });
        });
      });
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
    callback(response.user);
  })
}
```

userDAO.registerUser()

```
let registerUser = (dataToSet, callback) => {
  console.log("data in DAO", dataToSet);
  console.log("insert into Users set ? ", dataToSet);
  dbConfig.getDB().query(`insert into Users set ? `, dataToSet);
}
```

It shows this CORS error when it calls itself the second time in the browser console

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/register-user. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/register-user: 0 Unknown Error auth.service.ts:33:12
ERROR 0 core.js:9110:19
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a unique key constraint is meant to protect your datatable but it doesn't mean your server shouldn't protect your datatable too.

In your AuthService, try to retrieve any entry from your database for the provided unique email. If any entry is returned throw an error and don't call `userDAO.registerUser()`.

Comment: This code was borrowed from one of my older project where it worked. I thought of this work around but is it possible to get to the root of the cause. Also is it possible that this problem is caused by event bubbling?

Comment: Found the solution!! I forgot to add callback to query call in userDAO.registerUser().
I will also need to implement what you suggested though, to avoid user re-registering themself. Thanks for your help. @YeongHun Chan 's answer also helped me to find the cause of problem. So I dont know who's answer I should accept.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check a point where called twice or more through using `console.log` or debugging with the breaking point. And prevent multiple calling.
2. Set the email field to the unique key in DB. Throw 'duplicate' error.
3. Check this a link for CORS issue(https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors)

I hope this helps you. thanks.

Comment: console.log inside the subscribe is not reached!!

Comment: Found the solution!! I forgot to add callback to query call in userDAO.registerUser(). Thanks for your help. @Gérôme Grignon 's answer was also helpfull. So I dont know who's answer I should accept.